# Entity Framework - Existing Database, classes in seperate library

Tags: entity-framework

I'm looking for information about using entity framework with an existing database, but to keep my poco classes in another library.

I've done this a number of times in the past, but I've always ended up with my model classes in my data access library using EF and my domain classes in a separate library.  Inevitably this meant writing code to translate between my domain classes and my model classes.  This seems pointless and inefficient since the classes are usually almost identical.

Can anyone point me to a walkthrough keeping my classes are materialized by EF in a separate library?  I would need to be able to do some minor name correction (eg Filter_Rule --> FilterRule).  I would also like to be able to keep anything EF specific in the data access library so that I can swap out the data access library if I need to.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be quite straightforward. Create a DbContext code-first style as normal, adding DbSets and configurations as necessary to tell EF about your database. Set your initializer to null so it doesn't try to mess with your existing database, and voila...

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<YourPoco> YourPocos { get; set; }

    static YourContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
    }

    public YourContext() : base("database_name")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<YourPoco>().Property(x => x.FilterRule).HasColumnName("Filter_Rule");
        //OR
        builder.Configurations.Add(new YourPocoConfig());
        //OR
        builder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof (YourContext).Assembly);
    }
}

public class YourPocoConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<YourPoco>
{
    public YourPocoConfig()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.FilterRule).HasColumnName("Filter_Rule");
    }
}
```

If you are worried about getting everything to match your database structure, you can use Entity Framework Tools for Visual Studio to reverse engineer your models, then match the configuraiton or copy the generated POCO's into your other library and convert the data annotations into respective `EntityTypeConfiguration` classes to keep the POCO's clean.

[MSDN document on reverse engineering code-first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx).